# Antonym of selfie

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I am looking for an antonym of *selfie*, meaning *a photo/portrait of others*.

The ancient Greek word for self is like *auto*, and what I am looking for is an English word for *hetero* (its opposite). Do you have any idea of that?

Comment: A "straightie?" ;-)

Comment: Did you really write "like" and survive an edit?

Comment: A selfie is a portrait of yourself. The opposite is a portrait of someone else. That is usually simply called a _portrait_.

Comment: @KCH *[like](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/like_1)*: similar to somebody/something.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the opposite of a *selfie* is a regular *shot*

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if a similar “problem” came up back in the days that some painters painted self-portraits. Some of them must have lost sleep over what to call the painting they made of someone else!

In painting and in photography, a painting or picture that has as its main subject a person or group of people is called a **portrait**.

I cannot think of *any* reason why the emergence of a neologism for the word self-portrait, a portrait depicting the same person that *made* the portrait, all of a sudden would invalidate the word *portrait* to mean what it always meant.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of a selfie is a Yousie

Comment: Or a "theysie"?

Comment: Or a (somebody)elsie?

Comment: 'Yousie' retains some of the Australian flavour of 'selfie' too!

Answer (score 1):

I think a good, short antonym that fits the techie context is a **themsy/themsie**.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression you are looking for something kinda cute that is the counterpoint of selfie.

The most ready antonym of self might be "**other.**"  "Otherie" doesn't have much of a ring, does it? Though, keep in mind that in academic writing, Other is a concept that is an opposite to the familiar and accepted. To Other someone is to place them outside of the bounds of accepted familiarity and has ties to complicated issues of race, gender, and sexuality.

We talk of the self as being the **subject** or subjective. While the other is the **object** or objective. Try cruising around a bit on [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/objective) looking at both synonyms and antonyms to see if you can find one that works like selfie.

I found **mark, target, subject, that, pick**. None of which seems perfect.

I didn't find any easy counterparts to selfie that would themselves make a cute word to refer to a picture of another person. Maybe you will have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of selfie is elsie. It conveys "somebody else" and yet has the cuteness to perhaps catch on.

Comment: The Urban Dictionary (I know it's not reliable) already lists an "elsie" as a photo that includes a person taking a selfie, whether deliberately or not.

Answer (score 0):

While "The Blue Marble" is specifically used of one particular picture of the earth, other pictures of the earth are also called "blue marble images".

Since they are the only pictures which include almost everyone, or indeed in some cases absolutely everyone, except the photographer, the antonym of *selfie* is "blue marble image".