# Could "selfue" be a sensible antonym of "selfie"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A selfie is a photograph a person takes of themself.

By this definition, the antonym of *selfie* must be a photograph of oneself taken by somebody else. In *selfie* the **i** can be taken to mean “taken by me (I)”. In that case, in *selfue* the **u** would mean “taken by you”.

Is it possible that this word could arise and be used?

Comment: Maybe but I am not allowed to comment there. I need some 50 points. and also the expectation of author of that question is a photo of somebody else. Ideally it should be the photo of self taken by somebody else.

Comment: I'd just blog it as an **otherie** and let gentle readers figure out the meaning for themselves.

Comment: You would need 50 points to **comment** there, but why would you want to comment? You want to **answer**. It's a protected question, so you need 10 points to answer there, which you can gain quickly by answering other questions.

Comment: About as sensible as pictyou're.

Comment: I don't think that's a fair comparison, @EdwinAshworth. "Pictyou're" would be bad, but still superior.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm a bit surprised that _selfwe_ hasn't caught on as a term for a photo of multiple people taken by one of them. And indeed, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=selfwe) confirms that some people are already at work trying to introduce it.

Answer (score 5):

The word *selfie* does not in any way derive from *I*. The base word is simply *self*. The *-ie* suffix is simply a way to derive one noun from another.

Now, words derived without proper reference to the etymologies of their compounds do exist. Witness, as example, *homophobia*, which etymologically should mean “fear of self”. However, this works best when people don’t know where the parts come from. And the origin of *selfie* is quite transparent, so *selfue* seems, to me, unlikely to take off. Also, opposite words with such similar sounds are rare in English.

Answers in the related question for the [antonym of selfie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166841/antonym-of-selfie) suggest possibilities such as *yousie* and *elsie*, deriving from *you* and *else*. These might or might not catch on, but they are at least based on something real, which cannot be said for *selfue*.

And besides, what is the antonym of *selfie*? A selfie is not simply a photo taken of oneself. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/selfie) gives,

> A photograph that one has taken of oneself, typically one taken with a smartphone or webcam and shared via social media.

Similarly, [WordSpy](http://wordspy.com/index.php?word=selfie) finds an early definition of the word which doesn’t even mention taking the photo yourself:

> This is, as the kids would say, a “selfie,” a photo taken with the intent to post it to social media sites.
> — Alexis Madrigal, *The Atlantic*, September 10, 2012

A photo taken by someone else would probably be called a *portrait*, which is assumed not to be a portrait of oneself unless it is called a *self-portrait*.